# How to auto-resume the last played file in VLC

Tags: vlc

It's annoying having to browse through my directories, find a media file and seek to the appropriate location. Every time it is not possible to watch a movie fully in one sitting. Hence, when I return to VLC later, it should automatically load and resume the last file played. Is there a hack with VLC that can allow me to do that?
Or else, can we write a script to find the last played files from the VLC logs and play it?
**NOTE**: I'm not asking to auto-resume a file when I manually search through the directories and open it. I know it can be done in the new VLC update. My question is specific: just open vlc from command line and it should start playing the last media file.

Comment: I'm looking for the same, & the only answer below seems to refer to a plugin that doesn't exist.  Were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to install resume playback fron vlc market .

please read the below tutorials how to do it.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2889846/streaming-media/vlc-update-adds-in-app-extensions-resume-playback-android-tv-support-more.html